# How to have a div container width increase to the right from the left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container that holds some buttons to the extreme top right of a page.

I have set its position to fixed and given it a specific width and height which is needed.

The problem is when the text on the buttons increases it goes off the page. I can set overflow to hidden which will prevent it from moving off my button but then the text will get cut off.

The question I pose is, how can I move my div to the left of the page when the text grows but the position of the container to the left must remain the same?

[image]

css

```
#Container {
    z-index: 9000;
    height: 300px;
    width: 260px;       // im guessing this 3 height,width,and position is the problem but they can not be changed.They are needed.so is there a way i can do this maybe in jquery? 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
   direction:rtl  // i tried adding this but my container doesnt move the text cuts off to the left.
}
```

attempted

```
function TextGrow() {
            var right = $('#Container').offset().right;
            $("#Container").css({ right: right }).animate({ "right": "0px" }, "slow");
        }// didnt do anything
```

Comment: The `width` of your container can't increase if you limit it with a fixed value. Have you tried declaring that width as a *minimum width* instead? E.g: `min-width: 260px;` Better to include your markup as well so people can troubleshoot a working example, an MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

If your container has to have a miminum set width but must grow when its contents exceed that minimum width then use `min-width`.

The example below adds content to the top-right container by clicking the body. Its initial size is larger than its contents, but as the content grows, so does the container.

```js
var text = "Click body "
$("body").click(function(){
  text += "Click ";
 $("div").html(text);
})
```

```css
div{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: black ;
  color:red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click body</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi eius molestias accusantium quo consectetur laudantium consequatur, iusto suscipit soluta expedita reiciendis numquam fugiat cum laborum, culpa voluptatem ipsam pariatur minus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas dicta inventore fugit modi voluptatum dolorem dolor at tempore? Voluptatum cupiditate consequuntur, est corrupti. Non dolore sunt facere mollitia excepturi, obcaecati.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est dolor consequuntur officia. Numquam mollitia neque qui consequatur aliquid culpa consectetur sint, rerum facilis alias, quo voluptatem omnis incidunt ratione odit!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur asperiores ex aperiam, eos modi assumenda, accusantium architecto sit. Sequi id ipsam, a earum quibusdam esse harum, atque provident repellendus accusantium!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur asperiores ex aperiam, eos modi assumenda, accusantium architecto sit. Sequi id ipsam, a earum quibusdam esse harum, atque provident repellendus accusantium!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur asperiores ex aperiam, eos modi assumenda, accusantium architecto sit. Sequi id ipsam, a earum quibusdam esse harum, atque provident repellendus accusantium!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur asperiores ex aperiam, eos modi assumenda, accusantium architecto sit. Sequi id ipsam, a earum quibusdam esse harum, atque provident repellendus accusantium!</p>
```

Comment: YES! something like this, but not when its clicked.But thank you this helped

Answer (score 2):

Try to add these css commands:

```
min-height: 100px;
max-height: 100px;
width: auto;
float: right;
```

Make sure parent container does not go outside the screen.